# FastReport CrossTab Column Header Rotation

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, fastreport

I have a FastReport CrossTab report with long column names, which would expand into multiple pages if I were to print it. I thought maybe I can rotate the column headers in order to save some space. But FastReport does not compute proper Y position for rows, and the generated report looks like this:

[image: Report]

Notice the yellow rotated headers, and the overlapping data rows. The first data row is positioned correctly, for the following rows are not. I have set the `Rotation` property of the `TfrxMemoView` FastReport has generated for column header to `90`. What should I do for the rows to be placed in proper vertical positions?

I'm using FastReport Version 4.12.12

Comment: I've just checked this on empty project in D2010 with **FR-4.9.9** and DXE2 with **FR-4.13.1**, Everything is OK. There is something else, because not only column headers overlap in your screenshot. Make sure that `ShiftMode` is set to `smAlways` for memos.
How do you fill cross-tab,  in OnBeforePrint event or something else ?

Comment: @teran `ShiftMode` is set to `smAlways`, and the data is coming from two client datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. If the `MasterBand` is smaller than the `TfrxDBCrossView` inside, FastReport can not calculate the vertical position of rows correctly.